# XML Schema not well-formed, what is my issue?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

The error I'm getting when checking validity is:

```
Not valid.
Error - Line 8, 40: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; 
columnNumber: 40; s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_xmtma' 
is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.`
```

The piece of code it's referring to is:

```
<xs:element name="xmtma">
    <xs:complexType>
       <xs:element ref="contact" /> <!--LINE 8-->
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="contact">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="personal" />
            <xs:element ref="company" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an `xs:element`-Element as a child to your `xs:complexType`-Element. Have a look at: [W3-Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_complextype.asp) for the Syntax of `xs:complexType`-Elements in XML-Schemata.

You could wrap your `xs:element` inside a `xs:sequence` for example.

```
<xs:element name="xmtma">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence (... additional attributes ...)>
      <xs:element ref="contact" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought sequence was optional, only if you wanted it to appear in a certain order, I thought it was unnecessary as it only had one child.